# Naming of the chemical elements and original sentences by the discoverers

Tags: terminology, elements, periodic-table, history-of-chemistry

Does anyone recall a printed or an online compilation where the names of all the chemical elements are listed along with the *original sentence*, from a research paper, containing the name of the element? The unabridged Oxford English Dictionary is great resource for name origins but it obviously does not mention the very first non-English paper.

Take for example krypton, the etymology in the *OED* is "Etymology: < Greek κρυπτόν, neuter of κρυπτός hidden, concealed. Discovered by Ramsay in 1898." Such information is available everywhere. What was the original paper by discoverer when he wrote about it this *new* element? Many discoverers often gave some interesting logic behind their choice.

Another example is of *Die Zerlegung des Didyms in seine Elemente* by Carl Welsbach, in Monatshefte für Chemie 1885, 6 (1), 477–491.

> Da sonach die exacte Zerlegung des Didyms in mehrere Elemente
> realisirt ist, so schlage ich vor, die Bezeichnung Didym nunmehr ganz
> zu streichen und beantrage, für das erste Element, entsprechendder
> Grïnfärbung seinerSalze und seiner Abstammung die Benennung: Praseodym
> mit dem Zeichen Pr und für das zweite, als das „neue Didym", die
> Benennung: Neodym mit dem Zeichen Nd.
>
> Since the exact decomposition of didymium into several
> elements has been realized, I propose that the designation didymium
> now be deleted altogether and that the first element, corresponding to
> the green coloration of its salts and its origin, be designated:
> Praseodymium with the symbol Pr and for the second, as the "new
> didym", the name: Neodymium with the symbol Nd.

This website [https://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/36/krypton#history](https://www.rsc.org/periodic-table/element/60/neodymium#history), has a small history section for each element but I am looking for quotes (German French, English, etc.) like the above from the original papers that contain the proposed names of the elements. I tried searching but could not find a single compilation.

1. Does anyone recall a resource like that?
2. Where can one find the first official of modern elements (Z > 92), which state the name of the elements? Does IUPAC make that information public?

Comment: Side info: Note that there are very interesting podcasts [chemistry in its element](https://chemistryinitselement.libsyn.com/rss) and [Episodic table](https://feeds.podcastmirror.com/episodictable), with websites https://episodictable.com/ and [chemistryworld - chemistry-in-its-element](https://www.chemistryworld.com/chemistry-in-its-element-the-elements/218.subject)

Comment: I'll look into this actually because this is pretty interesting. The two resources I would go to would the the Merck Index and also the Chemical Rubber Company Handbook for Chemistry and Physics. It has some pretty cool explainations into symbolic representation orgins and the traceback to russian/greek.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics

Answer (score 6):

The mere [list of chemical element name etymologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_element_name_etymologies) probably will not satisfy you.

- Reviewing the old elements up to #104, I recall «Discovery of the elements» by Mary Elvira Weeks/Henry W. Leicester published by the *Journal of Chemical Education* [sic!].  Pick up your library card on [archive.org](https://archive.org/) for a 1 h screening borrow [here](https://archive.org/details/discoveryofeleme07edunse) (7th edition, 1967).  While each element is presented in its own portrait, the chapters are grouped by topic, e.g. the elements known to the ancient world (Au, Ag, Cu, Fe, Pb, Sn, Hg, S), the halogens (except At), the noble gases, natural radioactive elements (Ra, Po, U, Rn, Pa, Ac, Th), discoveries by X-ray spectrum analysis (Hf, Re), or modern alchemy (Fr, Tc, Pm, ...).  The one hour offered to you there won't suffice for the 900+ pages compiled.  Includes cross references to primary literature, too.
- If you don't have this much time, look out for *The Merck Index*.  Though the subtitle reads *An Encyclopedia of Chemicals, Drugs and Biologicals*, and contains many more organic than inorganic chemicals, you equally find a brief characterization of the elements including some of properties and (if not known for too long) some references about its discovery. For example $\ce{_{99}Es}$:

  [image]

  credit:  *The Merck Index*, 13th edition, Merck & Co Whitehouse Station NJ, 2001, p. 3562, e.g. on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/merckindexency00onei).  Available for a borrow for up to 14 days, [link to the page](https://archive.org/details/merckindexency00onei/page/624/mode/2up) *after* using your library card.

  Because of the handy (sub)structure search, some groups/institutions favour the electronic access of this resource on [https://www.rsc.org/Merck-Index/reference](https://www.rsc.org/merck-index) (currently 15th edition, 2013).

Comment: Thanks Buttonwood. I was not aware of Merck Index listing the origins, I will certainly check. I had a copy of Elvira's book. Pretty nice. I had actually used for my Journal of Chemical Education article on re-discovering iodine.